# Is there a way to "fill in" a series of datetime stamps?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary that consists of an hourly datetime stamp (seconds since the epoch) as they key, and an integer as the value for each. Currently, I have an incomplete series of hourly datetimes, and I'd like to fill in any gaps.

What I mean is, if I have an entry for 5/15/2015 17:00:00 and an entry for 5/15/2015 19:00:00, but nothing for 5/15/2015 18:00:00, is there a way to quickly iterate and fill in those missing hourly keys with a value of, say, "0".

I have a large amount of raw text data that includes dates in this format: YYYY-mm-DD HH:MM:SS, which I round to the hour (by converting to seconds since epoch using datetime.datetime.strptime, and truncating the minutes and seconds), and essentially count how many times each hour shows up in the raw data. So my dictionary looks like {'2015-04-02 04:00:00': 1, '2015-06-06 13:00:00': 4, ...}. There are hourly gaps and I would like to fill them quickly and efficiently.

My current solution involves finding the min of the dictionary keys, and creating a brand new dictionary and filling in every hour until the max of the original dictionary. THEN I just redo the code I wrote to create the original dictionary, which changes the values that have data to change, but leaves the "empty" values as 0. Obviously not elegant...

Comment: Please demonstrate your issue with a short snippet that allows others to see the problem directly.

Comment: When you say "datetime" are you actually using the `datetime` module, or are those just strings or something else?

Comment: I will include a snippet to show my problem, but yes, I am using datetime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An solution could be:

```
import datetime

# your dictionnary
data = {...}

start = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(0)
step = datetime.timedelta(seconds=3600)

stop = datetime.datetime.now()
while start <= stop:
    key = start.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
    if key not in data:
        data[key] = 0
    start+= step
```

But, is it worth filling the gaps? or your use-case would be [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)?

Example:

```
>>> data = collections.defaultdict(int)
>>> print data['5/15/2015 17:00:00']
0
```

Comment: You never increment by `step`. I'm confused.

Comment: It is important for me to have the gaps filled with zeroes where there is no data.

Comment: I think this is the best idea, though I'd reorganize a bit (don't change `start`, make a new variable `now` that we're stepping through. Don't do `timedelta(seconds=3600)`, do `timedelta(hours=1)`)

Answer (score 3):

You could extend the `dict` class by something like this:

```
class FilledDict(dict):

    def __missing__(self, i):
        if any(k < i for k in self.keys()) and any(k > i for k in self.keys()):
            return 0
        raise KeyError()
```

and then use it like any dict:

```
In [2]: fd = FilledDict()

In [3]: fd[2] = 3

In [4]: fd[4] = 5

In [5]: fd[1]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-e8f6ba432654> in <module>()
----> 1 fd[1]

/tmp/ipython_edit_lfgvSO/ipython_edit_OrM6Oj.py in __missing__(self, i)
      4         if any(k < i for k in self.keys()) and any(k > i for k in self.keys()):
      5             return 0
----> 6         raise KeyError()

KeyError: 

In [6]: fd[3]
Out[6]: 0
```

It might be worth noting that you can convert any dict into a FilledDict:

```
In [10]: d = dict(a=1, b=2)

In [11]: fd = FilledDict(d)

In [12]: fd
Out[12]: {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```